# Pandas: Insert rows from one dataframe into another at specific location based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have two dataframes such as:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'BarCode': ['12345678ABCD', '67890123ABCD', '12345678DEFG', '67890123DEFG'], 
                    'Description': ['Apples', 'Milk', 'Oranges', 'Yoghurt'],
                    'Quantity': [99, 77, 10, 52],
                    'Price': [12.0, 10.5, 11.0, 15.6],
                    'Extracted_Code': ['12345678', '67890123', '12345678', '67890123']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'BarCode': ['123456780000', '678901230000', '456721340000'],
                    'Description': ['BarCode1', 'BarCode2', 'BarCode3'],
                    'Extracted_Code': ['12345678', '67890123', '45672134']})

> df1

    BarCode         Description   Quantity    Price    Extracted_Code
0   12345678ABCD    Apples        99          12.0     12345678
1   67890123ABCD    Milk          77          10.5     67890123
2   12345678DEFG    Oranges       10          11.0     12345678
3   67890123DEFG    Yoghurt       52          15.6     67890123


> df2

    BarCode         Description    Extracted_Code
0   123456780000    BarCode1       12345678
1   678901230000    BarCode2       67890123
2   456721340000    BarCode3       45672134
```

If `Extracted_Code` in df2 matches the `Extracted_Code` in df1, insert the matched row from df2 at the start of the matched group in df1. My desired result:

```
    BarCode         Description   Quantity   Price   Extracted_Code
0   123456780000    BarCode1      NaN        NaN     12345678
1   12345678ABCD    Apples        99.0       12.0    12345678
2   12345678DEFG    Oranges       10.0       11.0    12345678
3   678901230000    BarCode2      NaN        NaN     67890123
4   67890123ABCD    Milk          77.0       10.5    67890123
5   67890123DEFG    Yoghurt       52.0       15.6    67890123
6   456721340000    BarCode3      NaN        NaN     45672134
```

I want to achieve this result in the most optimized way possible. This is what I have done but I am not able to get the desired result:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2[(df2.Extracted_Code.isin(df1.Extracted_Code))]]).sort_values(['Extracted_Code', 'Quantity'], ascending=[True, False], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach is to use two `concat`'s

```
m = df2['Extracted_Code'].isin(df1['Extracted_Code'])

result = pd.concat([df2[m], df1]).sort_values('Extracted_Code')
result = pd.concat([result, df2[~m]], ignore_index=True)
```

Result

```
        BarCode Description Extracted_Code  Quantity  Price
0  123456780000    BarCode1       12345678       NaN    NaN
1  12345678ABCD      Apples       12345678      99.0   12.0
2  12345678DEFG     Oranges       12345678      10.0   11.0
3  678901230000    BarCode2       67890123       NaN    NaN
4  67890123ABCD        Milk       67890123      77.0   10.5
5  67890123DEFG     Yoghurt       67890123      52.0   15.6
6  456721340000    BarCode3       45672134       NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to sort values with stable sort:

```
>>> (pd.concat([df2, df1])
       .sort_values(['Extracted_Code', 'Quantity'], 
                    ascending=[True, False], 
                    na_position='first',
                    kind='stable',
                    ignore_index=True))

        BarCode Description Extracted_Code  Quantity  Price
0  123456780000    BarCode1       12345678       NaN    NaN
1  12345678ABCD      Apples       12345678      99.0   12.0
2  12345678DEFG     Oranges       12345678      10.0   11.0
3  456721340000    BarCode3       45672134       NaN    NaN
4  678901230000    BarCode2       67890123       NaN    NaN
5  67890123ABCD        Milk       67890123      77.0   10.5
6  67890123DEFG     Yoghurt       67890123      52.0   15.6
```